# Air Canada only giving partial refund on canceled ticket within 24 hours of booking?

Tags: bookings, refunds, air-canada

I'm trying to cancel a flight that was booked less than 24 hours ago, I'm seeing that Air Canada does not want to refund the full ticket amount, but [their policy appears that they should refund the full amount?](https://www.aircanada.com/content/aircanada/ca/en/aco/home/fly/customer-support/cancel-booking.html) Am I missing something or this correct? Currently trying to get through to them on customer service but can't.

[image]

Comment: probably whoever coded that didn't special-case the 24 hour thing and this is just generic cancelling. Call someone before the 24 hours are up.

Comment: This looks like an after-24-hours cancellation. Are you quite certain of the time? Regardless, you should call them immediately.

Comment: Those rules often apply per country - and some airlines enforce them as such. If you buy a ticket from the US, you have the right for a full refund within 24h (I don't know for Canada). If you buy from another country, those country's rules apply, and the might be different. The airline might just allow everybody that option, but not all do.

Answer (score 2):

[This Canada Air webpage](https://www.aircanada.com/content/aircanada/us/en/aco/home/fly/customer-support/cancel-booking.html) says a booking made online may be cancelled for full refund within 24 hours. If that's how you booked, you're entitled to cancellation and full refund.

Push harder.